# Dealing with __turboFloat and the Borland toolchain

Tags: c, c++builder, borland-c++

I've been trying to ressurect a XP-era .dll that uses Microsoft's Uniscribe, prossible VCL and other artifacts to do some transliteration. It was compiled at the time with some Borland toolchain and the project i was handed includes .res files from Visual Studio, .mrt and .mbt files which also seem to be GUI-related, .ide files which are Borland C++ Project files, .dsw Turbo C Context files (opening 'em in a text editor - they could also be VC6 files... shuders), .bpr BCB.04.04 / BCB IDE files, .dfm font-related files and .bpg BWS.01 files. I feel like a digital Indiana Jones, minus the whip and dust makes me sneeze.

I got a Borland toolchain from Embarcadero and was using Code::Blocks, only somewhere among the line `-Weverything` gets into the compiler arguments, which the Borland doesn't like.
LLVM's Clang currently barfs on winnt.h (which i'd rather not edit), on stuff like

```
\um\winnt.h:1341:1: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
```

Visual Studio's compiler barfs on something else entirely (didn't bother with it much, though) and i don't remember where did MinGW/GCC stop.

I've had to fiddle with includes and libs (mostly the ones from Embarcadero's include\ and lib) and compiler flags (currently _NO_VCL _MSC_VER=1200 BUILD_DLL) on account of a bunch or different errors and won't even bother with the warnings. Using the cmd line to compile this project (with one of the .bpr files and Embarcadero's [documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/bcc32_xml.html) as reference) i managed to compile an .obj with this:

```
"C:\path\to\bcc32.exe" -w -tWM -tWD -y -vi- -v -a8 -r- -Od -D_NO_VCL -D_MSC_VER=1200 
    -I"C:\path\to\include\windows\crtl" 
    -I"C:\path\to\include\windows\vcl" 
    -I"C:\path\to\include\windows\rtl" 
    -I"C:\path\to\baseProjectDir" 
    -I"C:\path\to\baseProjectDir\subDir" 
    -oobj\Debug\myFile.obj -c ..\file1.cpp ..\subDir\file2.cpp ..\subDir\file3.cpp ..\subDir\file4.cpp
```

Yay. The fun continues when i try [linking](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/ilink32_xml.html):

```
"C:\path\to\ILINK32.EXE" /aa /Tpd /x /Gn /Gi /q 
    /L"C:\path\to\baseProjectDir;C:\path\to\baseProjectDir\subDir;C:\path\to\lib\win32\debug;C:\path\to\lib\win32\release" 
    "C:\path\to\myFile.obj"
```

i get:

```
Error: Unresolved external '__turboFloat' referenced from root
Error: Unable to perform link
```

Googlefu tells me this is some sort of Borland vendor lock-in thing, so i changed my link line to:

```
"C:\path\to\ILINK32.EXE" /aa /Tpd /x /Gn /Gi /q 
    /L"C:\path\to\baseProjectDir;C:\path\to\baseProjectDir\subDir;C:\path\to\lib\win32\debug;C:\path\to\lib\win32\release" 
    "C:\path\to\lib\win32\release\c0d32.obj" "C:\path\to\myFile.obj"
```

...and now it really hits the fan:

```
Error: Unresolved external '__dbk_fcall_wrapper' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external 'GetVersion' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__ErrorMessage' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_DLL_Lock' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_VCL_Init' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_MEM_UseBorMM' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_VCLLIB_Linkage' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__ExceptInit' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__pRawDllMain' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__startupd' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__free_heaps' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_VCL_Exit' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_DLL_Unlock' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__GetExceptDLLinfoInternal' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external 'HeapAlloc' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_TLS_SetValue' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_TLS_InitThread' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external 'GetProcessHeap' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external 'HeapFree' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_TLS_ExitThread' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_TLS_Free' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_TLS_Alloc' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external 'DllEntryPoint' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__argv_expand_ptr' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__wargv_expand_ptr' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__handle_setargv' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__handle_exitargv' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__handle_wsetargv' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__handle_wexitargv' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__fileinfo' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_TLS_GetValue' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0D32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__turboFloat' referenced from root
Error: Unable to perform link
```

I'm kind of at a loss here. Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since you have RAD Studio / C++Builder, why not open the project in that IDE and let it manage the compiler flags, includes, and libraries for you?

Comment: @JoshKelley because dependancy on proprietay 3rd parties is what got this mess on my desk in the first place and i'd prefer to keep it as agnostic as possible. Plus i don't really find the interface appealling/functional (and the properties window on a project is just unusuable - gigantic fonts for some reason). But i'm (also) giving it a try.

Comment: Understood, but since you're already dependent on their compiler and libraries, using their IDE to generate a project file may simplify your life. Once you have a project file, you can build it from the command line (using msbuild) and use your own IDE, instead of having to mess with libraries and includes yourself.

Comment: Otherwise, my only suggestions are to search for those unresolved symbols (tlib.exe or a good grep program may suffice) to see what additional .obj or .lib you may need. The C++Builder forums at forums.embarcadero.com may also help; there are some real product experts there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some pointers from the [forums](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=118234) and a [11 years old post](http://narkive.com/KbXrDD1n.4) i added some extra .obj to the link line, namely `cw32mt.lib` and `import32.lib`, so that the final line looks something like this (YMMV):

```
ilink32.exe -q 
-L"C:\path\to\lib\win32c\debug" 
-L"C:\path\to\lib\win32\debug" 
-LC:\MinGW\lib 
-LC:\path\to\myProject 
-Tpd /DEBUG 
obj\Debug\subDir\file1.obj
obj\Debug\subDir\file2.obj,
bin\Debug\final.dll,,C:\path\to\myProject\some.lib 
"C:\path\to\lib\win32c\debug\cw32mti.lib" 
"C:\path\to\lib\win32c\debug\import32.lib",,
```

It *is* one single line, with some `,,` and no spaces. Code::Blocks was handy too.